# Generating randomly the probabilities that sum to 1

Tags: r

I am trying to generate three probabilities that will necessarily sum to 1. I tried the following:

```
x <- sample(seq(0.05,0.95,0.05), size=3)
x <- boom/sum(boom)
```

However, I want the generated numbers to be fractions to two decimal places, i.e, numbers from 0.05 to 0.95 in steps of 0.05 (and so that they also sum to 1). The problem with the numbers generated by the code above is that they can be with many or infinite decimal places. How can I achieve what I need? Has anyone done anything similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```r
diff(c(0, sort(sample(seq(0.05, 0.95, 0.05), 2)), 1))
#> [1] 0.05 0.75 0.2
```

This works by choosing 2 random double-digit numbers between 0.05 and 0.95 and sorting them. The first number is the first sample, the second is the distance between the two numbers, and the third is the distance between the second number and 1, so they necessarily add to 1.

Note that if all the numbers have to add up to 1, and none can be lower than 0.05, this means none of the numbers can be 0.95.

For example, if we want ten such samples, we can do:

```r
t(replicate(10, diff(c(0, sort(sample(seq(0.05, 0.95, 0.05), 2)), 1))))
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#>  [1,] 0.25 0.15 0.60
#>  [2,] 0.25 0.25 0.50
#>  [3,] 0.30 0.05 0.65
#>  [4,] 0.25 0.50 0.25
#>  [5,] 0.50 0.05 0.45
#>  [6,] 0.45 0.20 0.35
#>  [7,] 0.10 0.85 0.05
#>  [8,] 0.45 0.50 0.05
#>  [9,] 0.15 0.40 0.45
#> [10,] 0.40 0.30 0.30
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: interesting distribution of probabilities: `x = replicate(10000, diff(c(0, sort(sample(seq(0.05, 0.95, 0.05), 2, TRUE)), 1))); barplot(table(round(x, 2)))` (to do with the sort then diff perhaps?)

Comment: That's interesting @user20650, though the constraints mean that there have to be fewer smaller numbers than larger ones. For instance, for each 0.5 drawn, there have to be two numbers smaller than 0.5 drawn. One would therefore expect this kind of distribution.

Comment: Though you've made me realize the sampling needs to be done without replacement, otherwise we run a risk of zero probabilities sneaking in.

Comment: @user20650 I'm sure there are a few distributions that would satisfy the constraints, but we can be sure that a uniformly weighted distribution cannot be one of them.

Comment: I'm convinced @Allan

Answer (score 1):

You can make many distributions over the discrete simplex you describe. Here is an alternative and generalizable way of generating a uniform distribution across all triples (p1, p2, p3) in your simplex:

```
p <- seq(0.05, 0.95, by = 0.05)
states <- expand.grid(p, p, p) # Generate all combinations
states <- states[rowSums(round(states, 2)) == 1, ] # Select simplex where elements sum to 1

states[sample(1:nrow(states), 1), ] # Sample a random element
```

This should work well for triples, but if you want to simulate from higher order simplexes (e.g. 7 probabilities or more) one should probably construct the data frame of states in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fn <- function(){
    s <- seq(0.05,0.90,0.05)
    sm <- sample(s , size = 2)
    while(sm[1] + sm[2] >= 1) sm <- sample(s , size = 2)
    ans <- c(sm , 1 - sum(sm))
    ans
}
```

by calling `fn()` you get the required sample

```
fn()

#> 0.20 0.65 0.15

fn()

#> 0.40 0.55 0.05
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. This will just sample the first element. and then loop over all other combinations of the second and third element and iteratively update them and return the last solution. In principle, this should give a solution where the last number was always 0.05, but due to floating point errors, there will be some variation (try e.g. s[6] + s[13] + s[1] == 1).

Comment: What about this  ? here i sample two number and the third must calculated automatically.